# Passing a function which returns array as a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have two functions:

```
function drawCard(player) {

let imageCard = document.createElement('img');
let imageId = getRandomCard();
player['cards'].push(imageId);
imageCard.src = "static/image/PNG/"+ imageId + ".png";
return [imageCard, imageId];}
```

and

```
function showCard(card, id, player) {
document.querySelector(player['div']).appendChild(card);
upgradeScore(id,player);}
```

I am trying to pass values **imageCard** and **imageId** returned from function **drawCard()** by calling a function **drawCard()** in **showCard()** arguments but I can't find the way to do so. Is there a nice and tidy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

You can use array destructuring to pass in the return values of `drawCard` as arguments for `showCard`.

```js
let player =  [...]
// ^ Assuming that you have declared the player variable elsewhere

showCard(...drawCard(player), player)
// The two values returned by the drawCard function are taken out of the array and passed in as arguments

// Equivalent to showCard(drawCard(player[0]), drawCard(player[1), player)
```

[More on destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is dependent on your player variable.

You can use it as the only argument and then call the drawCard method. Destructure the returned array into two variables and then use them as you wish.

```
function showCard(player) {
let [card,id] = drawCard(player);
document.querySelector(player['div']).appendChild(card);
upgradeScore(id,player);}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this help cause your demande is a kind of not clear.

```
function drawCard(player) {
    let imageCard = document.createElement('img');
    let imageId = getRandomCard();
    player['cards'].push(imageId);
    imageCard.src = "static/image/PNG/"+ imageId + ".png";
    return [imageCard, imageId];
}

function showCard(card, id, player) {
    let imageCardAndImageId = drawCard(player);
    document.querySelector(player['div']).appendChild(imageCardAndImageId[0]);
    upgradeScore(imageCardAndImageId[1],player);
}
```